# Blazored.FluentValidation and IBrowseFile

Tags: blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side, fluentvalidation

This is the code snippet:

```
@page "/fileupload"
@using Blazored.FluentValidation
@using FluentValidation

<EditForm Model="@model" OnValidSubmit="@HandleSubmit">
    <FluentValidationValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <p>
        <label>Name: </label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="@model.Name" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => model.Name)" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>File: </label>
        <InputFile OnChange="@OnFileSelected" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => model.File)" FluentValidation />
    </p>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private FileUploadModel model = new();

    private void HandleSubmit()
    {
        // Do something with the valid model
    }

    private void OnFileSelected(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        // Assign the selected file to the model property
        model.File = e.File;
    }

    // A validator class for the FileUploadModel using FluentValidation
    public class FileUploadValidator : AbstractValidator<FileUploadModel>
    {
        public FileUploadValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(m => m.Name).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Name is required");
            RuleFor(m => m.File).NotNull().WithMessage("File is required");
            RuleFor(m => m.File.Size).LessThanOrEqualTo(1024 * 1024).WithMessage("File size must be less than 1 MB");
            RuleFor(m => m.File.ContentType).Must(x => x.Equals("image/jpeg") || x.Equals("image/png")).WithMessage("Only jpeg and png files are allowed");
        }
    }

    // A model class for the file upload
    public class FileUploadModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public IBrowserFile File { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As simple as possible!
At the end, an input type="text" and input type="file" in a form.

Some version info:

- Blazor: 6.0
- Blazored.FluentValidation: 2.1.0

Input type"text" works, input type="file" doesn't. The line

```
<ValidationMessage For="@(() => model.File)" FluentValidation />
```

generates nothing! Remains totally silent, muted,...

This is the outcome:

[image]

Summary works, input text works

[image]

IBrowserFile (input file) doesn't

[image]

Any ideas? (Couldn't find any info so far.)

Comment: `<ValidationMessage For="@(() => model.File)" FluentValidation />` is the **FluentValidation** at the end a typo?

Comment: No, an attribute. With or without - no effect. A suggestion by Bing.

Answer (score 1):

The `<ValidationMessage For="@(() => model.File)"/>` is only showing messages for the `File` property and since the `File.Size` and `File.ContentType` are on their own `RuleFor()`'s those messages are not tied to that `ValidationMessage`.

You can combine the inner properties rules on top of the `File` propertys' rule.

```
public FileUploadValidator()
{
    RuleFor(m => m.Name).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Name is required");
    RuleFor(m => m.File)
    .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
    .NotNull().WithMessage("File is required")
    .Must(file => file.Size <= 1024 * 1024).WithMessage("File size must be less than 1 MB")
    .Must(file => file.ContentType.Equals("image/jpeg") || file.ContentType.Equals("image/png")).WithMessage("Only jpeg and png files are allowed");
}
```